# If you get a disability pension can your bank close your account if you can't pay their credit card?

Tags: canada, credit

I've been at RBC for 40 years and I have received a federal pension for disability for the last 25 years.

If because of this covid19 financial pressure and lack of affordability,  I can no longer make those credit card payments (RBC's Visa) and I default, can they take my pension or close my account?

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in?  My guess is that RBC = Royal Bank of Canada and that this is a question of Canadian law.  If so, please update the question to include that information.

Comment: Are you in debt?

Comment: thanks for your reply, it's RBC in BC, Canada! Thanks again, Appreciated!

Comment: What do the terms&conditions say?

Comment: Have you tried asking the Ministry of Social Development and Poverty Reduction.  They may be able to tell you how regulations and laws shape how the banks may behave in such circumstances.  Their contact phone number is 1-866-866-0800.

Comment: You don't say how covid has reduced your income.  Do you have other income.  No one is allowed garnish CPP, OAS or GIS except the CRA.  The bank doesn't have to let you have credit (or even an account).